# Loop script every N seconds without using Ajax or XmlHttpRequest or CORS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cors

This Code simply works fine.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http_get_url") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    echo $xml->parent->child1 . "<br>";
    echo $xml->parent->child2. "<br>";
    echo $xml->parent->child3;
```

I needed to loop it every N second, So I made a XmlHttp-Ajax request for it as shown below :

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>    
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var xhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open("GET", "http_get_url", true);
   xhttp.send();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
       var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
       var val1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('val1')[0].childNodes[0];
       var val2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('val2')[0].childNodes[0];
       var val3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('val3')[0].childNodes[0];
       document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML=val3.nodeValue;
       document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=val1.nodeValue;
       document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML=val2.nodeValue;
    }
  }
}
setInterval(myFunction,(2000));
```

This works fine if CORS enabled on the browser but I cant expect users to enable CORS on their browser.

And I dont have access to server inorder to enable CORS. How can I loop every N seconds without need of XmlHttpRequest or Ajax? or without CORS enabled on server side.

Comment: You can use `JSONP`. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: You can't. You'll have to use AJAX here, and why wouldn't you?

Comment: @KarolKlepacki: In what world does JSONP mean ***not using AJAX***?

Comment: I dont mind using Ajax but then I get No Origin Access Control error in console and dont see output. I need a way to work around. I tried adding header() in php file but no luck as the server does not support CORS

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Can you show an example of Ajax for the above code, I will try testing it.

Comment: Oh, I missed the error you're getting, you're making a X-domain request, that explains the CORS thing (I was wondering about why you got that). In that case: use AJAX with JSONP instead, JSONP is meant specifically for X-domain AJAX requests

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes, you are right. If you can help me prepare an answer using Ajax and JSONP for me to test.